# C# regex length of replaced captures

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I made a regex parser and I need to know, for each capture, what is the length of the replacement (without considering noncapturing groups).

For example let's say I have the following regex pattern `(?<=\w)"(\w+)"` and the replacement is given by `$1`.

Executing the regex it will look for all words (capturing group 1) in quotes that are preceded by a word chararcter and the result of the replacement will be the same string but without quotes.

To see this let's say I have this kind of input `a"foo" b"bar"`. In this case the regex will match `a"foo"` and `b"bar"` capturing `"foo"` and `"bar"`, the captures are than replaced by `$1` that is the first capturing group (the word inside quotes) so my resulting string will be `afoo bbar`. Well, the captures length is 5 characters while the length of the replaced captures is 3 characters.

Is there a way to find the lengths of the replaced captures? I tried to use the regex to replace the captures one by one and get the resulting length but this works only when there aren't noncapturing groups: the first capture is `"foo"`, if I pass this string as input the regex will not replace anything since the noncapturing group is empty, so the result length will be always 5.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var input = "foo\"bar\"";
            var pattern = new Regex(@"(?<=)""(?<word>\w+)""", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
            var count = 0;
            var output = pattern.Replace(input, m=>
                                         {
                                             var str = m.Groups["word"].Value;
                                             count+=str.Length;
                                             return str;
                                         });
            Console.WriteLine("output: {0}; count: {1}.", output, count);
            //will print - output: foobar; count: 3.
        }
    }
```

You can omit all captures by explicit capture option, which will tell engine to capture only specified parts of pattern.

Comment: I need a more general solution since the pattern is given by the user.

Comment: @PrinceOfBorgo then maybe you should ask clearly without excesse information about it? In your question I don't see a single question except one related to your example, let along you asking for general solution or that pattern is parameter too.

Comment: Literally the first sentence in my question says that "I made a regex parser and I need to know, for each capture, what is the length of the replacement (without considering noncapturing groups).". The example was a clarification for what I needed and for what solution I tried to use. Sorry if it wasn't clear.